# Check if there are multiple input fields with the same value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What is the simplest way to check with jQuery if we have multiple input fields on the page with the same value?

Thank you all!

Comment: Write a loop, make a list of current values.  Then run the same loop again and compare each value to what is in that list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can iterate all `input` elements, store their value in a hash table, and check if the value was already there:

```js
var hash = Object.create(null),
result = [].some.call(document.getElementsByTagName('input'), function(inp) {
   if(hash[inp.value]) return true;
   hash[inp.value] = true;
});
```

Comment: @DavidsonSousa I thought you were looking for a jQuery solution. You can check my answer for a jQuery based solution.

Answer (score 0):

Get all the input elements, sort and check if there are duplicates.

```
 var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("input")
    var values = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        values.push(elements[i].value);
    }
    var sortedValues = values.sort();
    for (var o = 0; o < values.length-1; o++) {
        if (values[o] == values[o+1])
            alert ('Duplicate!');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to write a loop and iterate through each input  field for a possible match. If you're using  **jQuery**, then it's actually very simple.

Let's say we have a simple HTML page with 3 input fields.

#### HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="input1">
<input type="text" name="input2>
<input type="text" name="input3">
```

Then we use the jQuery `each()` method to iterate over the fields. Mainly saying, we iterate over all the input fields and get their values. Then we again iterate through all the input fields (so were actually creating a nested loop) and check if any of them match the currently iterating input value.

#### jQuery:

```
 var currentInput;
$("input").each(function(index) {
  currentInput = $(this);
  $("input").each(function(index) {
    if currentInput.val() === $(this).val() {
      alert("Error: input fields match found");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Here you're matching only current and previous field, what if there's duplicate between first and second last out of 5 textbox?

Answer (score 0):

You can loop thru all inputs and generate a data structure like below.

```
var inputs = {};
$("input").each(function(i, elem) {
    if (inputs.hasOwnProperty(elem.value)) {
        inputs[elem.value] += 1;
    } else {
        inputs[elem.value] = 1;
    }
});
alert (JSON.stringify(inputs, null, 4))
```

[**A Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3v8hro0u/)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to provide a more efficient answer when it comes to checking for duplicate values in multiple input fields. When it comes to comparing values we need to,

1. Iterate and keep the current element somewhere temporarily
2. Re-iterate and check against the previously kept value whether its a duplicate
3. When performing the step 2, we need to make sure that we skip comparing the previously kept (step 1) value against itself.

If I am not wrong, I have seen step 1 and 2 in all above answers but not the step 3.

The following code will do all those 3 steps.

```
  var eqArr = []; 
  var currentInput;
  $("input").each(function(k1, v1) {
    if($(v1).val() != ''){
      currentInput = $(v1);
      $("input").each(function(k2, v2) {
        if(k1 !== k2 && 
           currentInput.val() === $(v2).val() &&
           $.inArray($(this).attr('id'), eqArr) === -1){
           eqArr.push($(this).attr('id'));
        }
      });
    }        
  });
```

In the above code I am collecting id's of those input fields of those duplicates (in array). After performing the above logic, doing following simple check will tell you whether you have duplicates or not.

```
if(eqArr.length > 0){
     //It means we have duplicates                            
}
```

```js
var eqArr = [];
var currentInput;
$("input").each(function(k1, v1) {
  if ($(v1).val() != '') {
    currentInput = $(v1);
    $("input").each(function(k2, v2) {
      if (k1 !== k2 &&
        currentInput.val() === $(v2).val() &&
        $.inArray($(this).attr('id'), eqArr) === -1) {
        eqArr.push($(this).attr('id'));
      }
    });
  }
});
console.log(eqArr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Input Field Duplicates</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" name="input1" id="i1" value="bbb">
  <input type="text" name="input2" id="i2" value="aaa">
  <input type="text" name="input3" id="i3" value="aaa">
  <input type="text" name="input3" id="i4" value="fff">
  <input type="text" name="input3" id="i5" value="bbb">
  <input type="text" name="input3" id="i6" value="ccc">
  <input type="text" name="input3" id="i7" value="bbb">
  <input type="text" name="input3" id="i8" value="bbb">
</body>
</html>
```